# Let $f: X \to Y$ be injective and $A \subset X$. Show that $f(X \setminus A) \subset Y \setminus fA.$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f: X \to Y$ be injective and $A \subset X$. Show that $f(X \setminus A) \subset Y \setminus fA.$

If I take $y \in f(X \setminus A)$, then there exists $x \in X \setminus A$ such that $y=f(x)$. But $x \in X \setminus A$ means that $x \in X, x \notin A$. So $y=f(x) \in Y \setminus A$? I’m not sure this is correct? Do I need the injectivity here at all?

Comment: Assume that $f(x) \in f(A)$ and derive a contradiction. Hint: You need to use injectivity somewhere in the proof by contradiction.

Comment: Observe that by injectivity your $x$ is the only point in $X$ such that $y=f(x)$, so if $y \in f(A)$ then...

Answer (score 1):

Option:

Let $y \in f(X$ \ $A).$

There is a $x_1 \in X$ \ $A$ with $y=f(x_1)$.

Assume $y \in f(A). $

There is a $x_2 \in A$ s.t. $y=f(x_2)$.

$f$ is injective:

$x_2=x_1=:x \in A\cap (X$ \ $A)$, a contradiction.

Hence $y\in Y$ \ $f(A). $